# How to create & store custom cache in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I am trying to create & store custom cache using script in magento 1.
Is their any way we can implement it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create your own cache type by declaring the following in your config.xml

```
<global>
    <cache>
        <types>
            <custom translate="label,description" module="module">
                <label>Custom Cache</label>
                <description>This is my custom cacge</description>
                <tags>CUSTOM_CACHE_TAG</tags>
            </custom >
        </types>
    </cache>
</global>
```

**Hope This Helps!**

**Update:** For more details refer to this link https://magently.com/blog/custom-cache-in-magento/
**Update:-**
**Retrieving Data**

```
Mage::app()->loadCache($id);
```

**Deleting Cache**

```
Mage::app()->removeCache($id);
```

**Checking If Cache Is Enabled**

```
Mage::app()->useCache('collection');  //check if cache group is enabled or not
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but i also want to store data in it.

Comment: wait am putting a source link in my ans now checkout the links

Comment: Let me try into script :)

Comment: yeah sure give it a try

Comment: @Chiiku How can i make sure that custom cache is created & stored ?

Comment: check updated ans

Comment: did it worked for you??

Comment: Yes, can you please take a look at here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317040/clear-custom-cache-from-cache-management-magento-1