# Clear custom cache from cache management Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I have created a custom cache using script.
cache is created successfully, i can get it too.

Added cache field for custom cache in cache management.

How to clear that cache custom cache from cache management Magento 1.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to clear our `example_id` cache, we can either do it simply from the admin panel in Cache Storage Management and then refresh “Blocks HTML output” or do it programmatically using `remove($cacheId)` or `clean(array($cacheTag))`.

```
Mage::app()->removeCache($id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am not sure where i can place the above code ? I have added a cache field in cache management to refresh only this cache. Its not working right now, so i need something that can clear it.

Comment: did you created a cache tag??

Comment: Yes, i have created a cache tag

Answer (score 1):

Check this article it might help you  http://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/refresh-magento-cache-programmatically/