# Overide cache clean method in custom cache - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

This is more a "Is it possible to do it" instead of "How to do it" type of question.

I have a custom module where I use the Magento 1.9 cache system to store the path of certain files. For example:

```php
Mage::app()->getCache()->save("path/to/file.txt", "MY_CACHE_ID")
```

So, in my cache, I have something like:

```php
array("MY_CACHE_ID" => "path/to/file.txt");
```

When I clear it using `Mage::app()->getCache()->remove("MY_CACHE_ID")` or refresh/clean all cache through admin panel, my cache is correctly deleted BUT my `file.txt` don't (as expected).

I want to know if it's possible to overide my cache's method used to clear the data of it to be able to delete (`unlink`) the file stored in it. Or even: delete all files inside the folder `/path/to/` whenever the cache is deleted using one of the above clearing methods.

I've across an "override option" to put in my module's `config.xml` like so:

```php
<config>
    <global>
         <cache>
            <types>
                <my_cache translate="label description" module="module">
                    <label>My Cache</label>
                    <tags>MY_CACHE_TAG</tags>
                    <backend_model>module/cache</backend_model>
                </my_cache>
            </types>
        </cache>
    </global>
</config>
```

And, in my `module/cache` model:

```
<?php

class My_Module_Model_Cache extends Zend_Cache_Backend
{
    protected function _clean($mode = Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL, $tags = array())
    {
        // Handle here the file deletion
    }
}
```

But the `_clean` method wasn't called.

I've also tried to find an event dispatched on cache's clearing, but didn't find any.
So, it's possible to do it?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317029/how-to-create-store-custom-cache-in-magento-1/317031#317031

Answer (score 0):

Inside the YourModule folder, create the following subfolders: etc, Model, and Cache.

In the **etc** folder, create a file named **config.xml** and add the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNamespace_YourModule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </YourNamespace_YourModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <cache>
                <rewrite>
                    <core>YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Cache_Core</core>
                </rewrite>
            </cache>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

In the Model folder, create a file named Cache/Core.php and add the following content

```
<?php

class YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Cache_Core extends Mage_Core_Model_Cache
{
    public function clean($tags = array(), $mode = Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL, $specificTags = array())
    {
        // Implement your custom cache cleaning logic here
        
        // Call parent clean method to perform the default cache cleaning
        return parent::clean($tags, $mode, $specificTags);
    }
}
```

Activate the module:
In your Magento installation root, open the app/etc/modules folder.
Create a new XML file named YourNamespace_YourModule.xml and add the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNamespace_YourModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </YourNamespace_YourModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

flush cache. Now, whenever the cache is cleared in Magento, your custom logic defined in the clean method of the YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Cache_Core class will be executed along with the default cache cleaning process.

Comment: Don't seem to work, have you tested it? Maybe another module is also rewriting it, so in my case it doesn't work, need to check. Also, it shouldn't be "<core>...<cache>...</cache></core>" instead of "<cache>...<core>...</core></cache>" in the config.xml?